# Cross-Domain, Client-Side Api Call without JSON or JSONP -- is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I didn't think it was possible to make a cross-domain, client-side api call and use the results within a web page without making the call using JSONP. A colleague recommended DOJO for this, but dojo.io.script seems to require jsonp.  If it's possible, I'll dig into the dojo some more -- but i'm thinking it's a lost cause.

Comment: No. Is not possible without JSONP. Using dojo/jquery will make things simpler.

Comment: [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

Comment: @igorw: CORS is not supported by every browser (Opera for example).

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 there is **limited support** for cross domain requests

see [HTML5 Security in a Nutshell](http://www.veracode.com/blog/2010/05/html5-security-in-a-nutshell/)

See also [Cross-domain XHR using postMessage](https://github.com/eligrey/pmxdr) and [HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)

Answer (score 1):

Other than Adardesign's answer, the only way would be to create a javascript bridge to a signed java applet and do this indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://engin.bzzzt.biz/2010/03/31/cross-domain-data-push-methods-compared/) comparison.